# SCIM Provisioning after Enterprise Application deleted

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I have an Azure Enterprise Application set up with Provisioning configured. It works fine. Now I want to completely delete the app.

**Does it trigger any SCIM requests** (e.g. `DELETE /Groups`, `DELETE /Users`) **when the application is deleted**? I could not find this use case in any docs. My guess and observation so far is it does not send any SCIM requests at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess/observation is correct. Deleting the application should cause it to stop tracking user/group changes and stop sending any requests for them. Deleting the app will definitely NOT cause a mass deletion event.